# Are Apache Common Math, Lombok, Apache Common Lang, Slf4j pure Java?

Tags: java, apache-commons, lombok, gluon

Are Apache Common Math, Lombok, Apache Common Lang and Slf4j pure Java?
No C/C++ libraies under the hood?

Just 100% Java?
Planning to use Apache and lombok for Android and Iphone via GluonHQ framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all pure Java, but just because they are pure Java does not mean they will necessarily work in Android as Android specifically identifies classes in the JDK it does not support.

Comment: Well. Why use Android Studio when GluonHQ uses Java 11 for both Android and IPhone?